# How to get custom Arg in configureStore reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I would like to give additional parameters for Dependency Injection to Reducer.

When I created the Store, I added Arguments like this.

```
export default configureStore({
  reducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      thunk: { extraArgument: { service } },
    }).concat(logger),
  devTools: true,
});
```

I know how to use it in createAsyncThunk function, but I don't know how to use it in other Reducer.  There is no third parameter.

In the following case, there is no third factor.

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logout: (state, action, third) => {

      // third is undefiend!!! it doesn't get value.
      // but createAsyncThunk does

      const { extra} = third;
      const { service } = extra;
      service.authService.logout();
      return {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        userId: null,
        profile: {
          name: null,
        },
        token: null,
      };
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like your `service.authService.logout();` is a side effect and side effects are never allowed in a Redux reducer. A reducer is only allowed to read `state` and `action` and (in the case of `createSlice`) modify `state`. No other side effects are allowed. So nothing like this will be available in your reducers.

You could be using the [listener middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware) for this though.

```js
listenerMiddleware.startListening({
  actionCreator: authSlice.actions.logout,
  effect: async (action, listenerApi) => {
    listenerApi.extra.authService.logout()
  },
})
```

Comment: I understand! Thank you.
To maintain the pure function reducer, I modified the service caller to "redux-thunks".